# What is the best way to clear Store except removelAll

Tags: extjs

when I am trying to clear store using removeAll function , after that grid is behaving differently, column disappears when I am trying add/remove column from grid .
   what is the best way to clear store?

Comment: The removeAll method should work.  Do you have any code showing what you are doing?

Comment: myStore.removeAll() but column header disappears after search record in grid .

Comment: This is known on SO as the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please make a fiddle showing your original problem, and a new question linking to that fiddle, and we will help you to solve your problem.

Comment: Did you try adding `myGrid.view.refresh();` after `myGrid.store.removeAll()` ?